# Suppose $AB=0$ for some non-zero matrix $B$. Can $A$ be invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

"Suppose $AB=0$ for some non-zero matrix $B$.  Can $A$ be invertible?"

I think $A$ is not invertible by proof by contradiction. Assume $A$ is invertible, then $A$ has a left inverse. Multiplying both sides we get $B= (A^{-1})(0)$. Now if the right side is compatible then it should be $0$ and we get a contradiction because $B$ is suppose to be a nonzero matrix. However, because the dimensions of the matrix $A$ and $B$ are not given, I'm not sure if this works. The zero matrix may not be matrix multiplication compatible with $A$ inverse.

However, this does tell us that in the case where $A$ and $B$ are square matrix, $A$ is not invertible if $AB=0$ where $B$ is nonzero.

Now what do we do about the cases where $A$ and $B$ are not square matrices?

Comment: Your solution is correct. For non-square matrices, we have only the pseudoinverse, in this case I do not think that we speak of an "invertible matrix". It is no problem , if $B$ is not a square matrix. The proof is valid also in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is good: you proved that $A$ cannot have a left inverse. In particular it cannot have a two-sided inverse, which is the condition for being invertible.

Knowing that an invertibile matrix is necessarily square is not required.

Just use a different name for the left inverse, say $L$.

Sizes are not of a concern: if $A$ is $m\times n$ and $B$ is $n\times p$, the the zero matrix is $m\times p$ and $L$ is $n\times m$.

Comment: oh ok thanks! I forgot to change the dimension of the left inverse and thought it was just m x n

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is invertible it is a square matrix. Now each column $y$ of $B$ satisfies $Ay=0$ which impllies $y=0$. So $B$ has to be the zero matrix.